# Having a problem trying installing Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: system-installation

when I'm trying ti install ubuntu on my laptop, my laptop gets a reset and stays on page.[image: photo of error message]

my laptop spec:

- AMD Ryzen 9, 4000 series
- RTX 2060 Max-Q